# Replacing binary files while rewriting Git repository history

Tags: git

I am archiving some old repositories, some of which contain very large compressed binary files. These files are in a format that supports an uncompressed representation, and the compression it uses isn't very good. I would like to take these files, decompress them, and then rewrite the repository's history, replacing the compressed files with the decompressed versions, and then bundle and compress the repository with LZMA.

How do I walk through the commit history and replace these files without touching any of the commit information?

I stumbled on `git-filter-repo` [which is able to replace text](https://www.mankier.com/1/git-filter-repo#--replace-text) using `--replace-text <expressions_file>`. Is the same possible for binaries?

Comment: It's easy enough in *theory*, it's the practical application that tends to be tricky. The old `git filter-branch` can do this too, it's just that filter-branch itself is horribly klunky. Since filter-repo is written in Python it's easy to write a little Python fragment to plug into it. The hard part is figuring out what to plug in where. I don't think you'll find any pre-written plugin for this.